# How can I load/import GIS file (ESRI Shapefile) to Unity3D at runtime?

Tags: unity, c#, augmented-reality, geolocation

I'm new to Unity3D and I need to implement an open source Markerless Augmented Reality GIS mobile app (Android, IOS) to show the underground utilities (like wastewater pipes, water pipes, electricity lines,...) when the user moves with the mobile camera.

I found some SDKs for Unity3d that use location based AR (like Wikitude, Vuforia, ARCore, ... ) but I have not found a way to load a GIS file format (like ESRI Shapefile, CAD, GeoDB, ... ) at runtime and draw (points, lines, polygons) in 3D Unity shapes in its geographic location.

Screenshot from ([vGIS](https://www.vgis.io/)) software to show what I need to implement 
[image].

Comment: SofttwareRecs.SE is not strictly for standalone software.  Check out their help section.  I think it is exactly what you are looking for.  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: While I think you're right that this question could get good answers on the Software Recommendations exchange, @Evorlor, I think it could also get good answers here. So if Ahmed GIS would prefer to ask here, I think we should give it a shot. To make this easier to answer in detail, Ahmed, can you please pick one specific format you want to load? Each different format might require different techniques.

Comment: @DMGregory to simplify my question:  i need to load an ESRI Shapefiles that contain lines features into Unity and draw them like the attached image at runtime.

Comment: @AhmedGIS if you're asking this on a different exchange, then we'll need to close the question here. StackExchange policy is to host each question on just one site, so it's up to you to choose which one you expect will give the best answers for your needs. Or you can modify the question to ask a different question on the two sites (eg. "What software/plugin can convert format X for use in Unity" vs "How can I write a Unity script that reads format X")

Comment: I think if you find a library, it will not be Unity-related. Given that, I don't see us having much knowledge on the subject here.

Comment: maybe this might be a suitable solution:
https://github.com/i2e-haw-hamburg/cad-in-unity

Comment: @Mampfi This was a link only answer. If you think it would solve the OP's issue, please create an answer and describe how they'd use that tool to solve the issue.

Comment: I m currently developing a similar app . Did you find any solution after all ?

Comment: @ThanosLoupas, Unfortunately i didn't find any solution yet.